# `recast` - adding a properties to an object

Tags: typescript, npm, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to modify properties to a particular typescript object with the library [`recast`](https://github.com/benjamn/recast).

This is the file content:

```typescript
// /path/to/my/file.ts
...

import somelib from 'somelib';

...

export const theobj:MyType = {
  thekey: {
    prop1: 5,
    prop2: 6
  }
} 

...
```

I want to remove `prop1` and add a `prop3` to prop `thekey` inside the object `theobj`.

This is my code:

```typescript
import fs from 'fs';
import * as recast from 'recast';

const source = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/my/file.ts', 'utf-8');

const ts_ast = recast.parse(source, {
     parser: require("recast/parsers/typescript")
});

const all = ts_ast.program.body;

for(const node of all){
    if(node.type === recast.types.namedTypes.ExportNamedDeclaration.toString()){
        const variable_declaration = node.declaration;
        const variable_declarator = variable_declaration.declarations[0];
        if(variable_declarator.id.name === 'theobj'){
            for(const prop_def of variable_declarator.init.properties){
                if(prop_def.key.name === 'theykey'){
                    for(let i = 0; i < prop_def.value.properties.length; i++){
                        const prop_obj = prop_def.value.properties[i];
                        if(prop_def.key.name === 'prop1'){
                            delete prop_def.value.properties[i];
                        }
                    }
                    
                    const id = recast.types.builders.identifier('prop3');
                    const value = recast.types.builders.stringLiteral("'a str value'");
                    const obj_prop = recast.types.builders.objectProperty(id, value);

                    prop_def.value.properties[0].insertAfter(obj_prop);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

const printed = recast.print(ts_ast).code;
console.log(printed);
```

Even though the `delete` works perfectly, the `insertAfter` does not.

I get:

```
insertAfter is not a function
```

I've checked and I saw that `prop_def` is a `Node` and not a `NodePath`. It is `NodePath` that has the method `insertAfter`.

In the [`README`](https://github.com/benjamn/recast#readme) it says: *"Now do whatever you want to ast. Really, anything at all!"*, but it doesn't say what are the methods to add a new `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to modify AST would be using [`Putout`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer, I’m working on.
Here is [`Replacer`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/engine-runner#replacer) code, it uses [`PutoutScript`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/compare#supported-template-variables):

```js
const from = `
    export const theobj:MyType = {
      thekey: {
        prop1: 5,
        prop2: 6
      }
    } 
`

const to = `
    export const theobj:MyType = {
      thekey: {
        prop2: 6,
        prop3: 'a str value',
      }
    } 
`


module.exports.replace = () => ({
    [from]: to
});
```

Looks this way:

[image: Putout transform example]

You can try it in [`Putout Editor`](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/8b06070a39bc749edee89745dbd0f8a5/3b43a1a0133ea3d8f668026c7d44e30ea75cf982).
It uses [`recast`](https://github.com/benjamn/recast) and [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) to get things working.

Comment: [Please disclose that you are affiliated with putout](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).